# Taylor Series Method for a first order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am asked to apply the Taylor Series method of order $1$ for the IVP $x' = \sqrt{x}$, $x(0) = 0$ and explain why the method differs from the $\frac{t^2}{4}$ solution.

So  $x(t+h) = x(t) + hx'(t)$. By the initial condition, $x'(0) = \sqrt(0) = 0$, so we have $x(t_0 + h) = x(t_0) + hx'(t_0) = 0 + h \cdot \sqrt{ 0 } = 0$.

Did I do the Taylor Series method correctly? How does this differ from $\frac{t^2}{4}$

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is asking when is says 'explain why the _method_ differs from the $t^{2}/4$ solution'. That question doesn't make sense. Notice that the IVP isn't Lipschitz, hence there isn't a unique solution to the problem ($x = 0$ also satisfies the ODE and data).

Answer (score 0):

Taylor series method is to use Taylor series, not just the linear term. That would give the first order Euler method. So one would need all of
$$
x(t+h)=x(t)+x'(t)h+\frac12x''(t)h^2+\frac16x'''(t)h^3+...
$$
Computing derivatives directly gives $x''(t)=\frac{x'(t)}{2\sqrt{x(t)}}=\frac12$, at least for $x(t)>0$. Thus all higher order derivatives are zero. The local solution is then $$x(t+h)=x(t)+\sqrt{x(t)}h+\frac14h^2=\frac14(2\sqrt{x(t)}+h)^2.$$

---

One could have a doubt about the initial point and division by zero. If a series expansion of the solution exists at that point,
$$
x(t)=a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+…
\\
x'(t)=a_1+2a_2t+3a_3t^2+…
$$
then it also satisfies the squared equation $x'^2=x$,
\begin{align}
(a_1+2a_2t+3a_3t^2+…)^2&=a_1^2+4a_1a_2t+(6a_1a_3+4a_2^2)t^2+…\\
&=a_1t+a_2t^2+a_3t^3+…
\end{align}
Comparing the constant terms one finds $a_1=0$. The linear coefficients are then automatically zero on both sides. In the quadratic terms $4a_2^2=a_2$ remains, which gives the variants $a_2=0$ and $a_2=\frac14$. And next
$$
a_3=12a_2a_3\implies a_3=0,\\
a_4=16a_2a_4\implies a_4=0,\\
…
$$
and so on, resulting in all remaining coefficients being zero.

The identified power series $x(t)=0$ and $x(t)=\frac14t^2$ can be confirmed as actual solutions for $t\ge 0$.

---

Note that there are infinitely many solutions of the form $\frac14\max(0,x-c)^2$, $c>0$, that are not analytical.